# OLS estimator question: using a subset versus using a dummy-interacted variables

Tags: estimation, least-squares, estimators

Suppose that we are interested in the following model:
$$y_i=\beta_1+\beta_2x_{i2}+\beta_3x_{i3}+u_i$$

Here, there is a dummy variable $d_i$.

I am wondering whether the following estimators are equivalent:

**[OLS using only the observations with $d_i=1$]** versus **[OLS $d_iy_i$ on $d_i1,\;d_ix_{i2},\; d_ix_{i2}$]**

That is, using the subset versus using the dummy-interacted variables.

When I run the both cases, the former yields a consistent estimator but the latter does not.

(even though the values of the dummy is random assignment)

the example R code is as follows:

```
x2 <- rnorm(100000, 2, 1)
x3 <- rnorm(100000, 1.5, 1)
x4 <- rbinom(100000, 1, 0.5)
y <- 1+2*x2+2*x3+rnorm(10000)
dt <- data.frame(y = y, x2 = x2, x3 = x3)
est <- lm(y~x2+x3, data= dt, subset = (x4 == 1))
summary(est)
nobs(est)

dt4 <- data.frame(y = y*x4, x2 = x2*x4, x3 = x3*x4, x4=x4)
est4 <- lm(y~x2+x3, data= dt4)
summary(est4)
nobs(est4)
```

Is there a way to do the same estimation without throwing away some of the data?

Why do they have different results?

Why the latter yields worse results despite the large number of observations?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example so that we can see what's going on. Please do that via the code `{}` tool on the toolbar.

Comment: Sorry about the omitted part. I added the code!

Comment: Why would you expect the two approaches return similar results? If you look at what `dt4` actually contains, you will find a number of rows filled with zeros. That is what is causing the difference.

Comment: @RichardHardy The reason is that in a textbook, I found a sentence that seems to imply the equivalence of the two estimations. But, I also think that there is no specific reason for that.

Comment: I see. The textbook may contain a poorly formulated statement, or you might have misread it.

Comment: There are many similar questions here, see the links at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574854/separating-datasets-vs-one-dataset-with-extra-categorical-feature#comment1061323_574854

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer:
The two regression should be the same because
$$[\sum_{i:d_i=1} x_ix_i']^{-1}[\sum_{i:d_i=1}x_iy_i]$$
using only the subsample with $d_i=1$ is equivalent to
$$[\sum_{i=1}^N x_id_ix_i']^{-1}[\sum_{i=1}^Nx_id_iy_i]$$.
The reason for the different results from the R code above is that the lm function do not make the interaction in the "intercept term".

see the following code and results is the same

`````
one <- rep(1, 1000)
x1 <- rnorm(1000)
x2 <- rnorm(1000)
d <- sample(c(1,0), 1000,replace = T)
u <- rnorm(1000)
y <- one+2*x1+x2+u

# using subsample
dt <- data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2,d=d)
est1 <- lm(y~x1+x2, data=dt, subset = (d==1))

# using interaction
X <- d*cbind(one,x1,x2)

# results
est1$coefficients
solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%(t(X)%*%y)
> est1$coefficients
(Intercept)          x1          x2 
  1.0077684   2.0358979   0.9949592 
> solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%(t(X)%*%y)
         [,1]
one 0.9547948
x1  2.0125214
x2  0.9677016
````
`````

Answer (score 1):

The way that you structured `df4` you effectively only included interaction (product) terms between the binary  `x4` and the original `x2` and `x3` predictors, while omitting the "main effects." That's generally poor practice, except in very limited circumstances. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11009/28500) for extensive discussion. If you structure that regression properly, e.g.:

```
est2 <- lm(y~(x2+x3)*x4, data= dt)
```

then all will make sense.